# extract error validation message from metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

If I have following html method for rendering input box with custom attributes like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Required]
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
}

public static MvcHtmlString ToolTipTextBox<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
                Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    ...
    bool isRequired = metaData.IsRequired ? true : false;
    string validationMessage = ???
}
```

Having `metaData` exposed for particular property how can I extract this
message from data annotation attribute **The Minutes field is required.** to the `validationMessage` variable?

Answer (score 0):

To access a code annotation attribute you must use reflection:

```
var attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>();
var isRequired = attribute != null;
```

Namespaces:

- GetCustomAttribute() - `System.Reflection`
- RequiredAttribute - `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

To get `type` you need to get the property type from the selector. If you weren't using a selector you might use something like `typeof(TModel).GetProperty("NameOfProperty")`. You could still use this method if you were to extract the name of the property from the selector. Just be aware there is no guaruntee that the selector returns a property (it could be a function result or even a field).

If `GetCustomAttribute<T>()` returns null that means that the property does not have an attribute of type `T`. Since you're looking to see if the `RequiredAttribute` exists that means the property is required if the attribute isn't null.

Comment: The code he or she posted would seem to be correct if the goal is only to determine whether a property is required by nature of its type or because of a `RequiredAttribute` annotation.  But I believe he can combine your answer with use of checking the `ErrorMessageString` property  of the attribute to get the error message it would emit.

Comment: Oh whoops, huge oversight on my part haha. I'll leave my answer in case it is still helpful, but yeah I failed to answer it fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the validation error messages for a property using

```
ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
Func<string, ModelMetadata, IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule>> ruleFactory = (name, metadata) => ModelValidatorProviders.Providers
    .GetValidators(metadata, helper.ViewContext)
    .SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules());
IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> rules = ruleFactory(propertyName, metaData);
```

and to get the validation message associated with the `RequiredAttribute`

```
ModelClientValidationRule requiredRule = rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ValidationType == "required");
if (requiredRule != null)
{
    string requiredMessage = requiredRule.ErrorMessage;
}
```